# Android App - View function

Tags: android

bit of a noob question, I think I'm going about this the wrong way.

This is my first app and I'm trying to set it up into multiple files and classes, my current problem:

For neatness and unforseen use in the future, I had placed my layouts into functions:

```
public void homepage (){
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_homepage);
}
```

I use the menu for most of my direct navigation and, previously, calling these functions in the
 onOptionsItemSelected () worked perfectly.

However, when I moved my page functions to a seperate class:

```
public class newpage extends MyApp {

    //Home
    public void homepage (){
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_homepage);
    }
....
```

and called them in the function:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    //Create new page class
        newpage pagecla = new newpage();
    ...

    pagecla.homepage();
    ....
```

It crashes the app, and when debugging the only sense I can make of it is a NullPointerException. 
I'm guessing I have to give it some kind of value for View, but I'm really not sure what.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. Each activity should have a call to the setContentView() function to intialise the function. Shouldn't need to externally reference it.

Answer (score 0):

You should invoke `setContentView` from your activity, not your `Application`. If you want to do this from your `Application` anyway (don't know why), you should provide a reference to your activity. But it's an awful design, plus you shan't name your class `pagecla`, you'd better read about java naming conventions.
It seems that you lack OOP knowledge also. Your function is in fact a method, which needs an object to be invoked on. It's your `Activity` before your refactoring and your `pagecla` after it.